# Menú opciones no aparece

Tags: android

Quiero poner un menú de opciones en mi app como el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al crear el menú, este no aparece en el `main_activity`, ¿Como lo añado?

Lo he creado tal y como aparece en la [documentación de Android](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions.html#add-actions)

Comment: Podrías poner el código que tienes ? Así seria mas fácil indicarte el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que aparezca debes sobreescribir el método `onCreateOptions()` , para esto, debes agregar el layout de tipo menu dentro del folder `/menu` (debes crearlo si no existe).

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_principal, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Como ejemplo, el archivo menu_principal.xml  debe tener una estructura similar a:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
          android:title="opcion 1"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
          android:title="help" />
</menu>
```

Revisa la **[documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)** acerca de como crear menus.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que crear en la ruta res/menu un xml con los item que quieras mostrar. Una vez hecho esto, en la actividad que quieras ver el menú, desde el método onCreateOptionsMenu, tienes que hacer:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nombre_del_xml, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Así ya debería de mostrarte el menú, si luego quieres añadirle funcionalidad al pulsar sobre las opciones solamente tienes que sobrescribir el método onOptionsItemSelected